# spark turn off dynamic allocation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

I want to make sure my spark job doesn't take more memory than what I pass, let's say 400GB is the max the job can use, from my understanding turning off dynamic allocation (spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = false) and passing --num-executors --executor-memory --driver-memory do the job in Cloudera stack? correct if wrong.

is there any other setting that I have to set to make sure spark job doesn't go out of limit.

Comment: You can limit the number of executors with dynamic allocation still enabled using _spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors_ setting. Actually IMO that would be the preferred way.

Comment: thanks, I want the job to go up let's say I want total control of my job 100Gb , 500GB , 1TB etc.... I don't want spark dynamic allocation to interfere so what I want is static allocation...

Comment: Check out this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution at my work Cloudera cluster has a special yarn parameter which doesn't let a job to go over certain limit which have to turned off or reset it.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Yarn-memory-allocation-utilization/td-p/216290

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_command-line-installation/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html